# There is a way to fill out the eureka form after pressing an external button to eureka?

Tags: swift, forms, eureka-forms, swift5

How can I create a form in which a text window can add a button on the left side, similar to the photo attached to the end?
The idea is that by typing textRow and clicking on the button to display the information that I search in a database and then display the Eureka form, it is possible to generate the Eureka form after pressing the Search button.
I consulted since in the view I can combine the eureka form with the text field and the Xcode button through a TableView, or how I can generate the eureka form after clicking "Search", since this button is not part of eureka
I hope you can help me with one of two ways.

This is to be able to load the information that I look for in a database (Firebase) and then display it in the eureka form.

Code form eureka:

```
form //+++ Section()
+++ Section()
    <<< DecimalRow(){ row in
        row.title = "Nota mínima:"

    }
    <<< DecimalRow(){ row in
        row.title = "Nota máxima:"

    }
    <<< DecimalRow(){ row in
        row.title = "Nota aprobación:"

    }
    <<< DecimalRow(){ row in
        row.title = "Exigencia:"

    }
    <<< DecimalRow(){ row in
        row.title = "Puntaje máximo:"

    }
    <<< DecimalRow(){ row in
        row.title = "Incremento:"

    }
```

I hope that the form can appear after pressing the external button of eureka with the data of the database.

[image: Attached image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

In case you are still looking for an answer, first identify the row by the tag value. Then set the value for it. Finally, reload.

Attached a sample code:

```
let row2: PhoneRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "total")
    row2?.value = "YOUR VALUE"
    row2?.reload()
```